# Linux grep with ampersand

Tags: grep

I'm probably missing something really dumb here, but I can't figure it out. Basically I have a list of SAS macro variables and I want to know where they are being used in my code base. For those unaware with SAS basically to use a macro variable you proceed it with the ampersand, so if the variable is named var1 you would reference it by &var1 (or &var1. but that's unimportant to this question).

So I've been searching using grep as follows:

`grep -iRw "&macro_variable" *`

I can't copy/paste the exact results, but I ran the following and it returned 0 results:

`grep -iRw "&lead_year" *`

Then I ran the following:

`grep -iRw "lead_year" *`

And it returned this line among others:

> parameters.csv:HPI_Hist_File,rreap_hpi_data_&lead_year.&lead_month.&lead_day..txt,rreap_hpi_data_&lead_year.&lead_month.&lead_day..txt

Why is grep finding files with an ampersand in front when I search for `lead_year` but not for `&lead_year`? This also isn't consistent, for most of my searches with ampersands in front it is successfully finding all results, it's just been this one so far where this was an issue.

Comment: grep (GNU grep) 2.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of your -w.

> ```
>    -w, --word-regexp
>           Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by
>           a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.   Word-constituent  characters
>           are letters, digits, and the underscore.
> ```

The key part being the "preceded by a non-word constituent character."  In your sample, &lead_year is preceded by an underscore.

Comment: Yep that did it, I didn't even remember why I used w I just sort of auto-piloted irw every time I grepped, I knew what the i and r meant but guess I shouldn't be using the w in this situation. I knew I was doing something dumb, thanks.